# $\liminf_n a_n = \inf_n a_n$ if $a_n \ge a_m$ when $n\mid m$

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, limsup-and-liminf, supremum-and-infimum

I would like to ask a reference for the following very easy result: can someone help?

Let $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of positive reals such that $a_m \le a_n$ whenever $n$ divides $m$. Then
$$
\liminf_n a_n = \inf_n a_n.
$$

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the question title. I was unable to make sense of it after reading it several times, mainly because I was reading it as one implication, where the left side made no sense. Hope that's ok. – I suspect a reference will be hard to find; as you say, the result is very easy, and I imagine it is rarely used.

Comment: I agree on everything, that's why I asked the question; by the way, thanks for editing the title. I already checked books of Bartle and Sherbert on real analysis, indeed I didn't find anything also between exercises :/

Comment: Yeah, your best bet would be an exercise where the object is to learn how $\liminf$ works.

Comment: I will continue to search in the meanwhile, thanks for your answer :)